# Gstreamer include SDT table

Tags: video, gstreamer, mpeg, transport-stream, dvb

Good morning
I have a problem encoding a video stream in transport stream (.ts)(mpegts) format using gstreamer.

I use the following Flow:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=4 ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, format=NV16_10LE32, framerate=30/1 ! omxh265enc qp-mode=auto gop-mode=basic gop-length=60 b-frames=0 num-slices=8 control-rate=constant target-bitrate=5000 prefetch-buffer=true low-bandwidth=false filler-data=true cpb-size=1000 initial-delay=500 aspect-ratio=0 ! video/x-h265, profile=main-422-10, alignment=au !  queue max-size-bytes=-1 ! h265parse ! queue ! queue max-size-bytes=188 ! mpegtsmux alignment=1 name=mux ! queue  ! Gstdmaproxy2sink
```

Where Gstdmaproxy2sink is a custom plugin

Is it possible to insert SDT tables into the TS flow?
since currently mpegtsmux only generates the PAT(PID=0), PMT(PID=32) and Video (PID=65) tables.

[image: TS Tables.]

Thank you so much

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=4 ! video/x-raw, width=1280, height=720, format=NV16_10LE32, framerate=30/1 ! omxh265enc qp-mode=auto gop-mode=basic gop-length=60 b-frames=0 num-slices=8 control-rate=constant target-bitrate=5000 prefetch-buffer=true low-bandwidth=false filler-data=true cpb-size=1000 initial-delay=500 aspect-ratio=0 ! video/x-h265, profile=main-422-10, alignment=au !  queue max-size-bytes=-1 ! h265parse ! queue ! queue max-size-bytes=188 ! mpegtsmux alignment=1  name=mux ! queue  ! Gstdmaproxy2sink